# How to serialize(marshall) array to each element

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I' trying to marshall and unmarshall XML file using Jackson library.

The source file is a 'team.xml' file below.
'team.xml'

```
<team>
    <member>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <tel_no>123-1234-1234</tel_no>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>John</name>
        <tel_no>123-4567-8901</tel_no>
    </member>
</team>
```

'<member>' element are two but are not wrapped into a container element like a '<members>'.

Anyway I succeeded to deserialize(unmarshall) 'team.xml' to 'Team.class' using @JsonSetter to 'public void addMember(Member)' of 'Team.class'.

```
String xmlStr = //
        "<team>\n" + //
                "    <member>\n" + //
                "        <name>Mike</name>\n" + //
                "        <tel_no>123-1234-1234</tel_no>\n" + //
                "    </member>\n" + //
                "    <member>\n" + //
                "        <name>John</name>\n" + //
                "        <tel_no>123-4567-8901</tel_no>\n" + //
                "    </member>\n" + //
                "</team>";

XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
Team team = mapper.readValue(xmlStr, Team.class);

System.out.println("------------ unmarshall -----------");
System.out.println(team);
```

Then I write an object of Team.class to XML string.
The result is folloiwng.... :(

```
System.out.println("------------ marshall -----------");
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(team));

XML string ...
<team>
    <member>
        <member>
            <name>Mike</name>
            <tel_no>123-1234-1234</tel_no>
        </member>
        <member>
            <name>John</name>
            <tel_no>123-4567-8901</tel_no>
        </member>
    </member>
    <name/>
</team>
```

Two '<member> elements are wrapped into '<member>', parent element.

How to serialize(marshall) an object of Team.class to XML string equals to 'input XML string'?

**That is, How to serialize(marshall) an array value to each value?**

Please, tell me how to solve this problem...

Thanks.

---------- JAVA Classes -----------

Member.class

```
package stackoverflow.question.xml;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

/**
 * 
 * @since 2021. 12. 21.
 * @version
 * @author Park_Jun_Hong_(parkjunhong77@gmail.com)
 */
@JsonRootName("member")
public class Member {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("tel_no")
    private String telNo;

    public Member() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getTelNo() {
        return telNo;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setTelNo(String telNo) {
        this.telNo = telNo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Member [name=");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append(", telNo=");
        builder.append(telNo);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Team.class

```
package stackoverflow.question.xml;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;

/**
 * 
 * @since 2021. 12. 21.
 * @version
 * @author Park_Jun_Hong_(parkjunhong77@gmail.com)
 */
@JsonRootName("team")
public class Team {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    private List<Member> member;

    public Team() {
    }

    @JsonSetter("member")
    public void addMember(Member m) {
        if (m == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.member == null) {
            this.member = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        this.member.add(m);
    }

    public List<Member> getMember() {
        return member;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setMember(List<Member> member) {
        this.member = member;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Team [name=");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append(", member=");
        builder.append(member);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you are trying to deserialize and serialize the xml in the wrong way. The Jackson library includes specific annotations for the xml like [`JacksonXmlProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html) and for the xml lists there is the specific [`JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html) annotation, so you have to rewrite your classes like below:

```
@Data
public class Team {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "member")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Member> member;
}

@Data
public class Member {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
    private String name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "tel_no")
    private String telNo;

}
```

For any further information you can refer to the links I included, below an example of deserialization and serialization of the xml you included:

```
Team team = mapper.readValue(xml, Team.class);
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(team);
System.out.println(s); //<-- it prints an xml as a string equal to the original one
```

Comment: Really thanks for your comment!!!!! I'll change my codes then report a result!!! thx!!!

Comment: @ParkJun-Hong You are welcome :-)